# Show unpulled remote commits in magit

Tags: magit

I'm trying to replace SourceTree with Magit and one of the features i can't understand how to reproduce in Emacs is to make it show me remote commits on the graph. In source tree that looks this way:

[image]

Is it possible to reproduce in Magit?

Comment: `l a` (`magit-log-all`)?

Answer (score 10):

Sure. Hit `f a`, which will run `git fetch --all`, it it will show you all the unpulled commits. You can then hit `RET` on a commit to bring up a detailed view.

In addition, after running `git fetch --all` in a terminal, `git status` will also tell you something like: "Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 82 commits, and can be fast-forwarded."

[image: Magit unpulled commits]